# Android: SQL rawQuery with wildcard (%)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having a `rawQuery()` with following sql string similar to this:

```
selectionArgs = new String[] { searchString };
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT column FROM table WHERE column=?", selectionArgs);
```

but now I have to include a wildcard in my search, so my query looks something like this:

SELECT column FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'searchstring%'

But when the query contains single quotes the following SQLite Exception is thrown: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range`

How can I run a rawQuery with selectionArgs inside a SQL query with wildcard elements?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to append the `%` to the selectionArgs itself:

```
selectionArgs = new String[] { searchString + "%" };
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT column FROM table WHERE column=?", selectionArgs);
```

Note: Accordingly `%` and `_` in the `searchString` string still work as wildcards!

Answer (score 20):

The Sqlite framework automatically puts single-quotes around the ? character internally.

```
String [] selectionArgs = {searchString + "%"};
Cursor c;
// Wrap the next line in try-catch
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT column FROM table WHERE like ?", selectionArgs);
```

That's it.

Comment: Yeb, but not wildcards

Answer (score 0):

Brad Hein's and Mannaz's solution did not work for me, but this did:

```
String query = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE column=%s";
String q = String.format(query, "\""+searchString + "%\"");
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q, null);
```